# Android Client-Server App & Web Services

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-volley

I have a website that I'm wanting to create a Java application for, and while I don't have any experience creating android applications I have a decent amount of Java experience and feel like I should be able to complete this task over some time. I'll be making use of the `Java.IO` package for client-side networking (On the application) and hosting a server using Java. This `server application` will have access to all of the same databases as the website through JDBC. (I'll be hosting it all on the same server.)

My question is how to go about handling connections on the android platform, currently I verify a dynamically generated salt with the database salt on every page refresh to prevent session theft. I also make sure that the encrypted password and the user-name stored in the session match.

I could theoretically just create a standard server application, using NIO and avoding the whole thread-per-client scenario. The problem is that my website has quite a bit of traffic, and I know the application will too. So I'm running into issues on how to handle it.

If I use a keep-alive TCP connection and store the users basic information in a class data structure (Psuedo example):

```
class User {
    int id;
}
```

Considering all information will be polled from a database and everything is relative to the id of an account, there's no reason to store any excess data into the User class, correct? Just a quick simple lookup tied to the connection to only get data relavent to yourself.

Should I avoid the use of TCP networking for this? What do you guys think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the server side, create REST web services that invoke CRUD operations on the server database, and return the responses to the client as a `JSONObject` or `JSONArray`. Android has internal support for JSON parsing, and you can use the [`Volley`](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley) library to call the web services. `Volley` is a pretty abstract, high-level HTTP library that makes it very easy to make REST web service calls. TCP connections are quite low-level and are not generally used in client-server Android apps. See the [**Transmitting Network Data**](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) tutorial for more on this.

Comment: Thanks, as for images should I have the server serve them in URI format, or just send a link of the image to the client and have it load it itself? Or are there better ways to do this?

Comment: You can send the URI to the client, and load the images in Android using the `NetworkImageView` class (also a part of Volley).